# Block encoding for a sum of Pauli terms

Tags: circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation

Given a qubit Hamiltonian with polynomially many local Pauli terms, what is the most natural way of constructing its block encoding? I know there are multiple ways of doing so, but I am looking for the one which would not use oracles but would instead rely on the fact that each Pauli term is a unitary itself (this seems cheaper to implement in the near term; the asymptotics would, of course, depend on the scaling of coefficients with the problem size).

I guess one way of doing so is by using the linear combination of unitaries (LCU) and multi-controlled gates. Is this actually the way go or better ways are already known? For example, I noticed [this implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.simulation.pauliblockencoding).

Even if the answer is vanilla LCU, I would appreciate showing the circuit, as I could never entirely grasp the construction of PREPARE and SELECT.